# $I \subseteq I_n$ and $I \neq \varnothing \implies I$ has the greatest element [Proof Verification]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Please check my below proof. Thank you for your help!

Definition:

> $I_n=\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid m \leq n\}$

Theorem:

> $I \subseteq I_n$ and $I \neq \varnothing \implies I$ has the greatest element.

Proof:

> Let $M$ be $\{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid \forall i \in I, i \leq m\}$. Then $n \in M \implies M \neq \varnothing$. By well-ordering theorem, $M$ has the least element $m_0$. Now we prove $m_0 \in I$. There are two possible cases.
>
> 1. $m_0=0$
>
> $\implies I=\{0\} \implies I$ has only one element $0$ and $0$ is also the greatest element of $I$.
>
> 2. $m_0>0$
>
> $\implies m_0=k+1$. If $m_0 \not \in I$, then $\forall i \in I, i < m_0$. Thus $\forall i \in I, i \leq k \implies k \in M \implies k+1$ is not the least element of $M \implies m_0$ is not the least element of $M$. (CONTRADICTION).
>
> As a result, $m_0 \in I$. So we have that $I$ has the greatest element.

Comment: Excellent......

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot, I have posted a question at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724438/a-is-a-finite-set-wedge-fa-to-b-is-a-surjection-implies-b-is-fi, but this question seems to receive no answer. Can you please check it out? I'm quite uncertain about my proof in that question!

Comment: See my answer to that question.